# How to create a loop in Bash to search a group of .gz files

Tags: bash

I am working on OS X El Capitan V10.11.3.

I was able to get the syntax to work with test files but am having a hard time using it on a group of .gz files.

Worked on test files:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
  grep $p test2.txt>> final.txt
done <test3.txt
```

I am trying to write a loop to search over 30 .gz files using a list of the SNPs in a "test3.txt” file.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
 grep $p zcat chunk?-chr*.imputed.info.gz >> Final.txt
done <test3.txt
```

The test3.txt file has 1 SNP that is represented in the .gz files. When I run the syntax above it creates a file proxy_imputed.txt but does not pull the SNP.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same platform but couldn't get your syntax to work - this seems to achieve the desired result (call it findString.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p ; do
  gzcat *.gz | grep $p >> Final.txt;
done
```

When run like:

```
./findString.sh < test3.txt
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track, but seems to work.  Note I had to use gzcat to read gzipped files, zcat was looking for *.Z